# Multiplying of two different sizes of DataFrame

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, database, numpy

[It needs to multiply the first row of ini_pop with all rows of Existing_Value and save it. How can I do this for all rows of the ini_ pop DataFrame?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xlDsi.png)

Comment: You need to be much more specific about what you want.  Do you want to save each row of one multiplied by the entire other dataframe?  Also, read [mcve].  The way you've presented this question requires any potential answerer to do too much work imo.

Comment: I want to save each row.

Answer (score 0):

This is a ridiculous question and deserves a ridiculous answer! (Generally I agree with @piRSquared)

```
import numpy as np
ini_pop = np.random.rand(10, 6)

Existing_Value = np.random.rand(149, 6)
Existing_Value = np.where(Existing_Value > .5, 1, 0)

results = {}
for i, v in enumerate(ini_pop):
    A = np.vstack([v]*149)
    results[i] = Existing_Value*A
```

ini_pop:

```
Out[62]: 
array([[0.597996  , 0.48470908, 0.34200821, 0.48973549, 0.31928532,
        0.00990472],
       [0.88490691, 0.85060902, 0.02761904, 0.67543623, 0.24011947,
        0.63160755],
       [0.51655439, 0.8541867 , 0.30350761, 0.91582466, 0.92503826,
        0.27640764],
       [0.14740895, 0.48664955, 0.39666046, 0.03173014, 0.44483261,
        0.81007225],
       [0.41793196, 0.63657912, 0.66755118, 0.56862476, 0.6962219 ,
        0.36292305],
       [0.99399587, 0.41775574, 0.15244959, 0.66047238, 0.27718652,
        0.29360273],
       [0.72210127, 0.51900693, 0.53540488, 0.91054719, 0.23536984,
        0.21565889],
       [0.98030203, 0.47739105, 0.22477224, 0.63551278, 0.73896193,
        0.06814704],
       [0.0152948 , 0.08646868, 0.42559336, 0.44558531, 0.29017913,
        0.64896315],
       [0.06043923, 0.83571793, 0.21154994, 0.87061577, 0.23682892,
        0.31632989]])
```

Existing_Value:

```
Out[63]: 
array([[1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1],
...
```

A (for the first row of ini_pop):

```
Out[67]: 
array([[0.597996  , 0.48470908, 0.34200821, 0.48973549, 0.31928532,
        0.00990472],
       [0.597996  , 0.48470908, 0.34200821, 0.48973549, 0.31928532,
        0.00990472],
       [0.597996  , 0.48470908, 0.34200821, 0.48973549, 0.31928532,
        0.00990472],
       [0.597996  , 0.48470908, 0.34200821, 0.48973549, 0.31928532,
        0.00990472],
       [0.597996  , 0.48470908, 0.34200821, 0.48973549, 0.31928532,
        0.00990472],
       [0.597996  , 0.48470908, 0.34200821, 0.48973549, 0.31928532,
        0.00990472],
...
```

results are stored as a dictionary and consist of each row of ini_pop being multiplied by the entirety of Existing_value (hence 10 values stored in the dictionary, one for each row of ini_pop).

Here's results[0]:

```
Out[69]: 
array([[0.597996  , 0.48470908, 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
        0.00990472],
       [0.        , 0.48470908, 0.34200821, 0.48973549, 0.        ,
        0.00990472],
       [0.597996  , 0.48470908, 0.        , 0.        , 0.31928532,
        0.        ],
       [0.        , 0.48470908, 0.34200821, 0.        , 0.31928532,
        0.        ],
       [0.        , 0.48470908, 0.34200821, 0.48973549, 0.        ,
        0.        ],
       [0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.48973549, 0.        ,
        0.00990472],
       [0.597996  , 0.48470908, 0.        , 0.48973549, 0.        ,
        0.00990472],
       [0.597996  , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.31928532,
        0.        ],
       [0.        , 0.48470908, 0.34200821, 0.        , 0.        ,
        0.        ],
       [0.597996  , 0.        , 0.34200821, 0.48973549, 0.        ,
        0.        ],
       [0.        , 0.        , 0.34200821, 0.        , 0.31928532,
        0.00990472],
...
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted to tell. I am new here. I continue to improve myself. Thank you for your attention.

Comment: Existing_Value = np.where(Existing_Value > .5, 1, 0)  Could you explain this line? What exactly did you do?

Comment: I just used that to make an example that is similar to your example quickly.  np.where() basically just thresholds a dataset, setting a value to 1 if the threshold is met, 0 otherwise.  It's not necessary to answer your question.